# Errors while uploading apk file in google play console

Tags: android, flutter, apk, google-play-console

I'm getting these 2 errors while uploading the APK file in the GooglePlay console:

> Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NO_APKS

and

> You cannot remove all production APKs and Android App Bundles

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: You made several value-langs direcories to set multiligual app titles under the 'app>src>main>res' directory. Remove them and create aab file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have created a release with no APK or App bundle in it, so there is effectively nothing to release.

Make sure to upload an APK or App bundle in the release.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error when uploading the App on Playstore and resolved through below steps.

1. In **build.gradle(app)**, change SDK version as **29**
2. Create again Signed APK with above changes in *compileSdkVersion 29* and *targetSdkVersion 29* and upload app on Playstore Console

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upload a fat APK then I got this error but when I uploaded three APK'S instead (armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86_64) then there was no error ,I couldn't even upload app bundle